# Calculating resistance in a circuit where relay is controlled by microcontroller

Tags: relay, resistance

[image]

I've been asked to calculate the theoretical resistance of R1 in the shown circuit. The information that I've been given is that the relay needs 60 mA and 12V. I've also been told that the transistor's hFE/Beta value is 20 and that the voltage drop between the base and emitter is 0.7 V. I've tried calculating the resistance of R1, but when I do I don't seem to use all of the information given which leads me to believe that I am doing it wrong. Furthermore, I am a bit confused as to what is meant by the term theoretical resistance of R1.

If anyone could lead me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What are you doing? Show your steps. Given the transistor's hFE and that the relay needs 60mA, you should be able to calculate a value of R1. You should use all of the information you gave us (hFE, 60mA relay current, 0.7V \$V_{BE}\$)

Comment: Add your calculations... often the question gives you more information than you need to obfuscate the path to the solution.

Comment: You also need to know the voltage of the I/O pin (often 5V).

Comment: @Shamtam, before all that, what's theoretical resistance though?

Comment: @TonyM I'd take that to just be the value calculated you'd use assuming ideal conditions (like \$h_{FE} = 20\$ or \$V_{BE} = 0.7V\$).

Comment: Well I get the resistance to be 1433.33 Ohms. I get this because there is a voltage drop of 4.3 V across the resistor (if we assume the I/O pin is 5 v) and the current on the base is 3 mA (because 60 mA/20=3 mA). R=U/I where U is 4.3 V and I is 3*10^(-3) A.

Comment: Noah, indeed 1433 is the max resistance you can use if the output reaches 5V. You need to back that off a bit (smaller). Other end criteria is the max current whatever is driving this can supply. To be even more accurate you would also need to factor in Vce sat....

Comment: In reality theoretical resistance is hogwash... theoretical range perhaps...

Comment: The theoretical part is if everything is as stated... Nothing ever is... so it is theoretical.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the 12V supply voltage for anything. It's not uncommon for questions to include some extraneous information.

If you assume the input to be a (theoretical) value the same as the MCU supply voltage it might be 5.0, 3.3, 2.5, 1.8 or something else entirely. A reasonable assumption might be 5.0, but you should state your assumption clearly.

In reality you would want to use a much lower value for the resistor than the value you will calculate above using Ohm's law and the nominal Vbe drop, to ensure deep saturation for the transistor and to account for the voltage drop in the MCU output transistor, voltage tolerances, temperature effects on the transistor, MCU output circuitry and relay coil etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since all transistor begin to saturate below Vce=2V , this means the current gain hFE slowly reduces towards 10% of its peak value hFE as Vce approaches the de facto spec for saturation of Vce(sat)=x at Ic/Ib=10.

This means it defines some low voltage like 0.2V using 10% of the current collector current in the base.  Often you can get away with 5% of Ic, but never 1%.

So now using Ohm's Law you can easily compute R1 based on the Coil DCR with 12V using 5 to 10% of Ic.

### Bonus info

The tradeoff is that low voltage Coils (<=5V) sometimes take more current than some CMOS are rated to drive, so users may compensate choosing 5% but 10% is guaranteed de facto saturation spec voltage specified at some temperature.

One important thing to understand is that all diodes and transistors alike have a saturation resistance, Rs ( or ESR or Rce or for FET's RdsOn), so that when used as a switch , the incremental rise in voltage with Current has a know slope that depends on the junction size.  *Diodes Inc.* call this Rce in their patented super low Vce(sat) switches in milliohms.  This "ESR" resistance may be used in future when high currents are used to predict voltage rise in diodes, Vce and LEDs.  Although not relevant here, unless it was a really big Relay with low DCR approaching that of the switch such as in a solenoid.  You usually want the Switch to be <=5% of the load DCR (dc resistance) so that if drawing a lot of current is efficient when switching inductive loads.